# Laravel - When do I have to filter user input?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using **Laravel** for creation of a web app and I am using a lot of user input(for `Model::find()`, and for models fields).

Which do I need to filter and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input::xx() does not filter anything, but laravel uses PDO's parameter binding, so as long as you use Eloquent models, you should not worry about SQL injections.